# Audio.play() rejected with NotSupportedError inside Electron webview

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm running an Electron (v2.0.3) project which executes scripts in a webview. One of the script is to play a local audio file under conditions.

However, the audio play is rejected if it's called inside a webview, while working fine if called in `index.html` or if an online audio file is played instead of a local one.

I've set `nodeIntegration` of the webview to true, and made sure the webview isn't muted. I guess it's not a problem about the auto-play policy because YouTube videos and online audio (e.g. http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/ambience_sounds/air_hum.wav) works perfectly if I load them in the webview.

Also, the file path and the file itself are no-problems, because it works good when I execute the script directly inside `index.html`.

Here's my `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <script>
        function init() {
            web.addEventListener("dom-ready", () => {
                web.executeJavaScript('<my-script>'); 
            }); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init(); ">
    <webview id="web" src="http://www.google.com" 
        style="width: 800px; height: 600px; "
        webpreferences="nodeIntegration=true"></webview>
</body>
```

Here's the content of `<my-script>`:

```
let path = `file://${require("electron").remote.app.getAppPath()}/xxx.mp3`; 
new Audio(path).play().then().catch(ex => {
    document.body.innerHTML = ex; 
});
```

After `Audio.play()`, the promise is rejected and show the error message:

```
NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
```

I've once thought about the chance of cross-origin limitations, but it seems not because I can play online audio files from different domains like I stated before.

How can I fix this? Could this be a bug? Or do I forget about some restriction? Any information would be appreciated. **Thanks.**

**Edit:** According to my further test, this error also occurs when I call `executeJavaScript()` on the `BrowserWindow.webContents` created by `main.js`. So it seems like a limitation about `executeJavaScript` rather than the webview.

The [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsexecutejavascriptcode-usergesture-callback) have mentioned the `userGesture` limitation, which can be configured by the second parameter of `executeJavaScript`. However, it doesn't work for me, still.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

add this line before the app start

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('autoplay-policy', 'no-user-gesture-required');
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work for me. But thanks for your answer.